# Penetration Testing on SIP-TLS Network?

Tags: voip, sip

Is it possible that SIP tools like [sipvicious](https://www.kali.org/tools/sipvicious/) and other SIP tools work on SIP-TLS networks where all of the devices (IP-Phones) have a certificate verify feature?

Comment: As far as I can see from a short search sipvicious does not support TLS at all. As for other tools - who knows. *"which all of devices (IP-Phones) has certificate verify feature?"* - I'm not sure what you mean with this. But if all devices expect their peer to be authenticated with a client certificate then you need to have an accepted client certificate - no matter which tool you actually use.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So it means without a client certificate i am unable to apply security tests?

Comment: If the peer requires you to authenticate with a client certificate then you need to do this - before you could do anything with SIP. This is how SIPS works: first comes the TLS handshake, then inside the TLS the SIP. This is the same as with HTTPS. The actual requirements of the client are unknown though, i.e. just because they have a *"verify feature"* does not mean that they actually enforce client authentication.